# OpenCV 3.4.2 VideoCapture reading AVI changes original video brightness

Tags: opencv

Hello I am facing very strange behavior while reading AVI video from disk using VideoCapture .

The problem is that there is difference in the brightness between the original image and the image was read using VideoCapture,feels like it applying some histogram equalization or other algorithm on my original image.

Original image:

[image]

VideoCapture image:

[image]

The original image was saved from "VirtualDub" program without any filters.

Read method :

```
VideoCapture videoCapture;
videoCapture.open(videoFileName);
Mat image;
videoCapture.read(image);
```

Any ides what can cause this ? sounds like codec (ffmpeg.dll) bug or anything else ?

Comment: Your code appears to just read a single frame. Is there a brightness difference all the way through the video?

Comment: @Mark Setchell  Yes in every frame, this frame is in the middle of the video.